# How do I pre-fill a Flask WTForms Form with existing data for an "Edit Profile" route?

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

### The problem

Whenever I write data to the attribute `form.[any-field-name].data`, the written data appears in the form, which is what I want. However, if a change is made in the form field when the form is rendered, the new value seems to only be stored in `form.[any-field-name].raw_data`. `form.[any-field-name].data` merely shows the original value that was written to `.data` before the user had the chance to type a new value in the field.

Obviously I could just grab the results from `.raw_data`, but that would defeat the purpose of having a form validation library. How can I elegantly pre-fill form fields for the user while allowing Flask-WTForms to accept fresh data from those same fields?

FYI: This is a bit different from a typical "edit profile" route, as my app creates a new `UserVersion` record every time a profile edit is made.

### The Flask route

```
@app.route("/edit_user", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit_user_self():
    """Edit user account that is currently logged in."""

    # get latest version of currently logged in user
    user_version = current_user.user_versions[0]

    # instantiate form and fill with existing data
    form = EditUserForm()
    form.username.data = user_version.username
    form.email.data = user_version.email
    form.addr_housenumber.data = user_version.addr_housenumber
    form.addr_street.data = user_version.addr_street
    form.addr_unit.data = user_version.addr_unit
    form.addr_city.data = user_version.addr_city
    form.addr_state.data = user_version.addr_state
    form.addr_postcode.data = user_version.addr_postcode

    if not form.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template("edit_user.html", form=form)
    else:
        # create new user version
        new_user_version = UserVersion(user=current_user,
            username = form.username.data,
            password = user_version.password,
            email = form.email.data,
            addr_housenumber = form.addr_housenumber.data,
            addr_street = form.addr_street.data,
            addr_unit = form.addr_unit.data,
            addr_city = form.addr_city.data,
            addr_state = form.addr_state.data,
            addr_postcode = form.addr_postcode.data
        )

        db.session.add(new_user_version)
        db.session.commit()

        flash("Changes saved")
        return redirect("/view_user")
```

### The form model

```
class EditUserForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        "Username", validators=[DataRequired(message="Please enter a username")]
    )
    email = StringField(
        "Email",
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Email(message="Please enter a valid email address"),
        ],
    )
    addr_housenumber = StringField("Housenumber", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_housename = StringField("Housename", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_conscriptionnumber = StringField(
        "Conscription Number", validators=[Length(max=80)]
    )
    addr_street = StringField("Street", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_place = StringField("Place", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_postcode = StringField("Postcode", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_city = StringField("City", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_country = StringField("Country", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_hamlet = StringField("Hamlet", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_suburb = StringField("Suburb", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_subdistrict = StringField("Subdistrict", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_province = StringField("Province", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_state = StringField("State", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_door = StringField("Door", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_unit = StringField("Unit", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_floor = StringField("Floor", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    addr_block = StringField("Block", validators=[Length(max=80)])
    submit = SubmitField("Save")
```

### Library versions

- Flask 1.1.2
- Flask WTForms 0.14.3
- Flask SQLAlchemy 2.1

Answer (score 3):

You need to swap your logic around. Test for form submission and validate first, else pre-populate and return the form:

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    form = MyForm()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #Validate and Process submitted form first:
        new_user_version = UserVersion(user=current_user,
                                       username = form.username.data)

        db.session.add(new_user_version)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/success')

    user_version = current_user.user_versions[0]
    #Pre-populate your form here:
    form.username.data = user_version.username

    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
your_form = FormObject(obj=your_instance)
# your_instance should have the same attributes that a FormObject has
# data will be stored in the html <input> value attribute
```

---------- old answer
I use [placeholder](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) for this purpose. You can pre-fill in the edit_user_self by mean of:

```
form.username.render_kw({'placeholder':user_version.email})
```

Oterwise you can do it in jinja like this:

```
{{wtf.form_field(form.email,
 placeholder=user_version.email)}}
```

but to do so you should pass additional information to jinja template.